# jQuery: get descendants doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm currently trying to code a nested checkbox. I already figured out to get the parent checkbox of a child checkbox, but whatever I try **it doesn't work to get it vice versa.**

I already tried to it with .children(), .find() etc, **which works only when it comes to something else than a checkbox**. When $(this) is a the object of a checkbox, it won't give me the previous element. How can I access to the first descendants object? Thank you !

HTML:

```
<ul class='main'>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="settings_overview" value="overview">Settings
         <ul class="sub"> 
             <li><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="add">Add device</li> 
             <li><input type="checkbox" name="add" value="delete">Delete device</li> 
         </ul> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').click(function () {

    var child = $(this).find(':first'); // not working

    var parent = $(this).closest("ul").siblings('input:checkbox'); // works

    console.log(parent);
    console.log(child);

    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v36xyfdn/11/

Comment: In your example, `$(this)` is the checkbox. `<input/>` tags are always self-closing. They can't ever have descendant or children elements. So you will always have to go up to a parent or closest element, and then do the find or siblings or something from there.

Comment: `$(this).next().find('input:first');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different scenerios, and those above code won't work at all times, and you might have to do fallbacks if it doesn't.
I've made the changes, perhaps this is what you were trying to achieve:

HTML:

```
<ul class='main'>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="settings_overview" value="overview">Settings
         <ul class="sub"> 
             <li><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="add">Add device</li> 
             <li><input type="checkbox" name="add" value="delete">Delete device</li> 
         </ul> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').click(function () {

    var nextUl = $(this).next("ul"); // not working
    var children = nextUl.find("input:checkbox");

    // if the clicked element was the child, then we won't get any children using above method
    if(children.length == 0){
        children = $(this).parents(".sub").find("input:checkbox");
    }

    var parent = $(this).closest("ul").siblings('input:checkbox'); // works

        // Works
    //console.log(parent);
    //console.log(children);


    // If there's a parent, then that means we're in the child
    if(parent.length){
        var activeChildren = 0;

      children.each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
            activeChildren++;
      });

      if(activeChildren == children.length){
        parent.prop("checked", true);
      } else {
        parent.prop("checked", false);
      }
    }

    // if the clicked element doesn't have any parent, means we clicked on the parent checkbox
    if(parent.length == 0){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
        children.each(function(){
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
        });
      } else {
        children.each(function(){
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
        })
      }
    }

    });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v36xyfdn/14/